# Ruby serial / parallel port manipulation

Tags: ruby, serial-port, hardware-interface, parallel-port

I wonder if some of you are working with hardware/circuitry via serial or parallel port in ruby, not with arduino or something similar, just sending receiving pulses thru the ports to a breadboard? or if someone knows a well documented library/gem or a good blog post on the subject.

So far I've found these the blog post about 'raw' port manipulation is very cool but short.

http://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2011/10/ruby-parallel-port-leds.html

these libraries seem nice, but don't have very good docs:
http://rubygems.org/gems/serialport 
https://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport/

Comment: Basically if anyone who has worked or played with PC ports with ruby can recommend library for it and or a good tutorial. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your link to my blog and was happy that it was described as "very cool", lol, thanks.

Not sure if it will help you any more, but I wrote a (slightly) longer post on this topic on the project's blog here:
http://tank.stevenocchipinti.com/2011/11/using-parallel-port.html

Mainly it has links to my github account with the examples that may be useful for you.

I opted for this "raw" approach because the code is actually quite simple (if you have linux) and there is less dependence on third-party gems, but I can totally understand the need for a simple library and am keen to see what you end up using.

Hope that helps, good luck!